# Python SSL Authentication Error - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, azure, ssl

We are testing out using AAD authentication on a Azure storage account instead of using the connection string.

When I run the code below I get the following error:

> azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Authentication
> failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
> unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import certifi
import os


AzureFilePath = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/AContainer/test1/'
AzureFileName = 'myfile.gzip'
LocalFilePath = 'c:\myfile.gzip'

csCred = ClientSecretCredential('theTenant', 'theClientID', 'theSecret')
account_url = "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net"

print(certifi.where())

try:
    #blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(_AzureStConnString)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=csCred)
    FullAzurePath = AzureFilePath + AzureFileName
    print(f'The Full Azure path is {FullAzurePath}')
    blobClient = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=AzureFilePath, blob=AzureFileName)

    print('Writing local file to Azure...')
    with open(LocalFilePath, 'rb') as data:
        blobClient.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True, connection_timeout=14400)
    print('Done')
except Exception as ex:
    #logging.exception(f'Blob error - {str(ex)}')
    print(ex)
    raise
```

I have installed certifi and i have the path to the cacert.pem... but I am not sure where I should add this info in my code to interact with the storage account.The examples I have seen are for HttpRequest/Response code which I am not using in the code snippet above.

I have added the cacert.pem path to a REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE system environmental variable and I have updated my certifi. I am using python 3.10.11

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like the issue is with SSL verification causing the connectivity to fail.

Is there a proxy in your corporate network ? Could you please follow the below action plan to isolate if this is indeed related to the proxy ?

**Plan 1:**
Could you please try to run the same command from a different machine which is on a completely different network? and check if that works.

**Plan 2:**
Try appending standard Python root CAs to your pem file and check if that helps to run the CLI command.

REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=$HOME/certs/internal.pem

**Plan 3:**
Try disabling SSL certificate verification temporarily by setting the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable to None and check if that helps to run the CLI command.

export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=None

This is not a recommended approach though.

**Plan 4:**
Run this command and check the result:
python.exe" -c "import urllib.request; print(urllib.request.getproxies())"

**Plan 5:**
You need to add HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to the system

**Plan 6:**
If you want to make this work with your Org's proxy then you need to follow the below:

```
import os
import sys
```

You need to update the proxy details below:

```
# TODO: Update this with your actual proxy information.
http_proxy = 'http://10.10.1.10:1180'
https_proxy = 'http://user:password@10.10.1.10:1180/'

proxies = {
    'http': http_proxy,
    'https': https_proxy
}
# Construct the BlobServiceClient, including the customized configuation.
service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, proxies=proxies)
```

More Info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_proxy_configuration.py).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Naveen, the company has a firewall but when i run the command above i get {}. The storage account is setup to use AAD for authentication only so the .from_connection_string function doesnt work. How would i pass in proxy info into the blob service client constructor used in my code snipped above?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Could you please use the below code snippet instead ? 

# Create a ClientSecretCredential using your Azure AD authentication information.
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

# Construct the BlobServiceClient with proxy and AAD authentication.
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=storage_account_url, credential=credential, **proxies)